# Mobile Phone : automatic call function

Tags: javascript

Good Day everyone,

I would like to ask if it is possible to automatically call the dialed number in mobile..

here's my code.

```
    <a href="tel:111-111-1111" data-rel="external"">CALL NOW!  111-111-1111</a>
```

the code is only dialing the number 111-111-1111.. but what I want is after dialing the number, the mobile will do the call function... is it possible in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if it's possible to override the os and initiate an actual call via JavaScript, then no.

The closest thing would be to fire a click handler on your anchor with the tel type href which *should* bring up a dialpad or prompt for the user to confirm the call.

Comment: thanks sir... the code already do that sir... it brings up the dial pad and auto dial the number... but sadly it is impossible to automatically call the dialed number.... so, thanks again sir.